# How to execute a scenario from a step in another scenario?

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-behave

Below is the example I want to execute a scenario in another scenario. 
How can I do this?
I've already known that I execute the other steps by using `execute_steps()`.

My environment:
macOS v10.14.1, Docker v18.06.1-ce, Django v2.1.4, behave v1.2.6, behave-django v1.1.0

```
Scenario: scenarioA
    Given ~
    When ~
    Then ~

Scenario: scenarioB
    Given scenarioA is completed # I want to exexute scenarioA here.
    When ~
    Then ~
```

Is there an api to run the scenario from the name of the scenario?
Is there an api that gets scenarios from scenario names and divides them into steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** This behavior is done deliberately, to eliminate collisions in cases where scenarioA falls during a call by scenarioB.

Behave API has only one method to call another step from current step: [execute_steps()](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#calling-steps-from-other-steps)

Official tutorial with exactly example: [macro step](https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial08.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot call a scenario A from scenario B. Behave does not support anything like that. But What you want here is executing all steps defined in scenario A in the first step of scenario B. We simply do this by create a dedicated step in step file.

> @given(‘all steps of scenario A is completed’)
>   def step_execute_scenario_A(context):
>   context.execute_steps(u‘’’
>              Given step~ A
>              When step~ A
>              Then step~ A ‘’’)

Scenario: scenarioB

```
Given all steps of scenario A is completed
When ~
Then ~
```